# SQL: built in function with table of text as an input

Tags: mysql, matlab, function

I am currently working with matlab and sql to identify shortest paths using midway points and extract some attributes of the resulting paths. I am facing some issues related to high computing time and I am trying to improve my code by developping a built-in function that would accept a table of sql queries as an input (I am a total begginer with functions in sql, I was only performing queries until now).

For now, I am using loops on matlab and calling the fonction for one observation at a time leading to high number of requests between the two softwares.

```
select * from fct_attribute_2(''insert into g_attributes %s'')
```

with %s being the shortest path function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fct_attribute_2(IN edge_sql text)
RETURNS TABLE(....) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN 
EXECUTE 'delete from g_attributes';
EXECUTE $1;
EXECUTE 'delete from g_attributes where edge=-1';
RETURN QUERY
(main function)
$BODY$
```

So what I am looking for is a way to have a table inclusing rows of text as the input and execute all these rows then perform the main function.

Does anyone have experience with similar functions ? Thanks a lot in advance and please tell me if I need to clarify any points.